# Icons in Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

In Laravel Spark 6.0, Taylor is using icons for the menus.  I cannot seem to figure out where these icons come from or how to add more icons like them.  In the code, he is using SVG.  I want to add more icons, change icon colors, etc, but am not sure where to start.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL8Zy.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's using Font Awesome

Answer (score 3):

I believe they are using fontawesome as their icon font, but the svg icons are zondicon. Steve Schoger designed Spark 6.0 and he also created Zondicons http://www.zondicons.com/icons.html